# Bitmap writing program doesn't produce a readable image despite following format specifications

Tags: c, file-io, bmp

I'm making a bitmap writer in C as part of a larger project. I followed the windows .bmp header format specifications and checked the generated file in a hex editor to compare it with functional .bmp images, however all image programs I have on my computer cannot open it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1) /* remove padding from sructs */

void generateBitmap(int width, int height, float dpi, const char* filename, pixel* imgData) {
    FILE* bitmap;

    struct fHeader {
        uint16_t type; 
        uint32_t size;
        uint16_t reserved1;
        uint16_t reserved2;
        uint32_t offset;
    }bmpFileHeader;

    struct iHeader {
        uint32_t headerSize;
        int32_t  width;
        int32_t  height;
        uint16_t planes;
        uint16_t bitCount;
        uint32_t compression;
        uint32_t imageSize; /* may be 0 if uncompressed */
        int32_t  xPPM;
        int32_t  yPPM;
        uint32_t colorEntriesUsed;
        uint32_t importantColors;
    }bmpImageHeader;

    int bytesPerPixel = 3; /* 24 bit color */
    uint32_t imgSize = width * height;
    uint32_t fileSize = sizeof(bmpFileHeader) + sizeof(bmpImageHeader) + (bytesPerPixel * width * height);
    int32_t ppm = dpi * 39;

    bmpFileHeader.type = 0x4D42;
    bmpFileHeader.size = fileSize;
    bmpFileHeader.reserved1 = 0;
    bmpFileHeader.reserved2 = 0;
    bmpFileHeader.offset = sizeof(bmpFileHeader) + sizeof(bmpImageHeader);

    bmpImageHeader.headerSize = sizeof(bmpImageHeader);
    bmpImageHeader.width = width;
    bmpImageHeader.height = height;
    bmpImageHeader.planes = 1;
    bmpImageHeader.bitCount = 8 * bytesPerPixel;
    bmpImageHeader.compression = 0;
    bmpImageHeader.imageSize = bytesPerPixel * height * width;
    bmpImageHeader.xPPM = ppm; /* typically set these to zero */
    bmpImageHeader.yPPM = ppm;
    bmpImageHeader.colorEntriesUsed = 0;
    bmpImageHeader.importantColors = 0;

    bitmap = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&bmpFileHeader, 1, sizeof(bmpFileHeader), bitmap);
    fwrite(&bmpImageHeader, 1, sizeof(bmpImageHeader), bitmap);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (width * height); i++) {
        fwrite(&imgData[i], 3, sizeof(char), bitmap);
    }

    fclose(bitmap);
}

int main(void) {
    pixel imData[4];

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        imData[i].r = 32;
        imData[i].g = 64;
        imData[i].b = 32;
    }

    generateBitmap(2, 2, 0, "bmptest.bmp", imData);

    return 0;
}
```

The end result should just be a monotone 2x2 image. Some examples I've found set some more header values, such as `imageSize` to zero, but other examples treated them as I have here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally got it to work. The problem was with the offset padding bits between rows of pixels. I personally didn't find it to be incredibly well documented, but the `.bmp` file format expects null padding bytes at the end of each row depending on the dimensions of the image. All I needed to do was add this line in to the pixel writing code:

```
int i;
int p;
for (i = 0; i < (width * height); i++) {
    fwrite(&imgData[i], 3, sizeof(char), bitmap);
    if ((i + 1) % width == 0) { /* if at end of scanline */
        for(p = 0; p < (width % 4); p++) {
            fputc('\0', bitmap); /* append appropriate # of padding bits */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In bitmap format, pixels are padded so that "width in bytes" for each line, is a multiple of 4 bytes. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage) for more details.

In this case you have 2 pixels per line, each pixel is 3 bytes. So you have 6 bytes per line. It has to be padded so each line is 8 bytes (the last 2 bytes are ignored).

This also affects the size of the bitmap file, and `imageSize` of `iHeader` structure.

```
int bytesPerPixel = 3; 
int bits_per_pixel = bytesPerPixel * 8;
int width_in_bytes = ((width * bits_per_pixel + 31) / 32) * 4;

...
bmpFileHeader.size = sizeof(bmpFileHeader)+sizeof(bmpImageHeader) + width_in_bytes*height;

...
bmpImageHeader.imageSize = width_in_bytes*height;
```

You want to rewrite the loop so it goes from top to bottom, left to right

```
for(int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int i = y * width + x;
        fwrite(&imgData[i], 3, sizeof(char), bitmap);
    }

    for(int x = width * bits_per_pixel / 8; x < width_in_bytes; x++)
        fputc('\0', bitmap);
}
```

`.xPPM` and `.yPPM` can be zero. Lastly you can use `#pragma pack(pop)` to restore compiler's default pack

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) /* remove padding from sructs */
    struct fHeader {
    ...
    };

    struct iHeader {
    ...
    };
#pragma pack(pop)
```